# How to move a div into another div with enough space using Laravel-Blade

Tags: html, css

I need some help with CSS especially positioning Objects in HTML in the correct position but in a responsive way (no hardcoded pos-y, pos-x an so on...)

The following div (in the picture) has this source code:

```
<div class="row" id="myFirstDiv">
    <picture class="col">
        <img src="FOOBAR" width="350" height="350"/>
    </picture>
    <div class="col" style="height: max-content">
        <div>FOOBAR Code for Size</div>
        <div>FOOBAR Code for Type</div>
        <div>FOOBAR Code for Gender</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image: Main div]
Lets imagine I use the code above as an extension for another template like in Laravel-Blade
 to extend a section

On my other template I have to use it like this:

```
<x-myFirstDiv></x-myFirstDiv>
<div id="mySecondDiv"> HERE IS SOME TEXT </div>
--- Maybe here is some code ---
```

Now my question, how do I position or move e.g. "mySecondDiv" into the Black-Bordered-Box with its X inside?

I tried to set the position for "myFirstDiv" as position: relative and float: left, but "mySecondDiv" with other divs underneath went to the right side of the whole purple box (see image). I expected "mySecondDiv" would move underneath the Image-Description right into the Black-Bordered-Box with the X inside.

Comment: it seems like you're looking for a variation of the "Holy Grail" layout: https://css-tricks.com/the-holy-grail-layout-with-css-grid/  get it to work with pure html/css then apply it to Laravel?

Comment: Hey @Kevon thx for your help! Unfortunately me and my colleagues changed the design because we did not find a solution yet. Maybe the Holy Grail Layout will be a good help for others having a similar problem as mine.